# In the CLI wallet, how can I send to an address book contact?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, address

Given a contact in the `address_book`, I would have expected to be able to send like so:

`transfer [address book index] [amount]`

Or: `transfer 3 4.321`

Can I directly use the address book entries as a transfer target or is it only possible to list those contacts via the `address_book` command?

*(It would also be cool to store tx priorities with address book contacts by the way.)*

Answer (score 3):

Sending directly to an entry in the address book is not possible at the moment. In monero-wallet-cli, those entries can only be used via the `address_book` command. This is something that's not very hard add though, and might be a good first patch for a new contributor.

Comment: Is this still not implemented?

Comment: Correct. spam for idiotic length check.